# Source for story about R' Yishmael ben Elisha's mother?

Tags: sources-mekorot, agada-stories-legends, kibbud-av-veim-honoring

This article tells us [the following story](http://www.chabad.org/library/article_cdo/aid/112326/jewish/Rabbi-Ishmael-Ben-Elisha.htm) about R' Yishmael ben Elisha and his mother:

> Rabbi Ishmael's mother was a very pious woman, and she worshipped her son. But one day she astonished the Sages when she appeared before them to complain about her son. Said she, "Rebuke my son, Ishmael, for he does not show me honor." The faces of the Sages turned pale, and they asked her, "Is it possible that Rabbi Ishmael should not show honor to his mother? What has he done to you?" She replied, "Before he goes to the Beth Hamidrash, I want to wash his feet, and to drink the water with which I have washed them, but he will not permit it!" Then the Sages said to Rabbi Ishmael, "Since this is her wish, honor her by permitting it.

What is the source for this story?

Answer (score 8, accepted):

Straight out of the Yerushalmi Talmud: [Pe'a 1:1](http://mechon-mamre.org/b/r/r1201.htm) and repeated in [Qiddushin 1:7](http://mechon-mamre.org/b/r/r3601.htm).

> אמו של רבי ישמעאל באת ואמרה וקבלה עליו לרבותינו אמרה גערו בישמעאל בני שאינו נוהג בי כבוד באותה שעה נתכרכמו פניהן של רבותינו אמרין איפשר לית רבי ישמעאל נוהג בכבוד אבותיו אמרו לה מהו עביד ליך אמרה כד נפיק מבית וועדא אנא בעה משזנה ריגלוהי ומישתי מהן ולא שבק לי אמרין הואיל והוא רצונה הוא כיבודה

Comment: Mazal Tov on reaching [established user](http://judaism.stackexchange.com/privileges/established-user) status! Would you please consider indicating, anonymously, [where you live](http://meta.judaism.stackexchange.com/questions/1635/where-do-you-live)? The more community members are accounted for there, the closer we come to being able to plan events to bring people together in person, some day.

Comment: Ooh nice idea! Done.